# How to increment/decrement characters in python in cyclic manner?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, encoding, character-encoding

I had created a function where I can increment and decrement character according to certain conditions and it's working absolutely fine for incrementing before "z" and decrementing characters that exist after "a"
Here is my working code for that :

```
str="a b c d e"
Posnew=""
Negnew=""
for i in range(len(str)):
    Posnew+=chr(ord(str[i])-i)
    Negnew+=chr(ord(str[i])+i)
print(Posnew)
print(Negnew)
```

but I don't know what logic should I create to cyclically rotate it which means if I decrement "a" then it should give "z" and if I increment "z" then it should give "a".

**Desired output would be something like if i decrement "a" by 2 then it should return "y" or if I increment "z" by 5 then it should return "e"**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should just check if result is bigger than 122 or smaller than 97. If you don't care about uppercase letters, the alphabet spans from a -> 97 to z -> 122, so just check if result goes beyond those two values and behave accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following script *increments* and *decrements* each character:

- by 1 for training and illustrative purposes initially, and then
- by i (i.e. by its position in the input string):

---

```
import sys
str="a b c e z" if len(sys.argv) == 1 else ''.join(sys.argv[1:])

Posnew=""
Negnew=""
for i in range(len(str)):
    ordstrP = ordstrN = ord(str[i])
    ordstri = ordstrP - 97                   #  97 == ord('a')
    if ordstri in range(26):                 #  26 == ord('z')-ord('a')+1
        ordstrP = ((ordstri +  1) % 26) + 97
        ordstrN = ((ordstri + 25) % 26) + 97
    Posnew+=chr(ordstrP)
    Negnew+=chr(ordstrN)

print('orig:', str)
print('or+1:', Posnew)
print('or-1:', Negnew)

print('-')

Posnew=""
Negnew=""
for i in range(len(str)):
    ordstrP = ordstrN = ord(str[i])
    ordstri = ordstrP - 97                   #  97 == ord('a')
    if ordstri in range(26):                 #  26 == ord('z')-ord('a')+1
        ordstrP = ((ordstri + (i % 26)) % 26) + 97
        ordstrN = ((ordstri + 26 - (i % 26)) % 26) + 97
    Posnew+=chr(ordstrP)
    Negnew+=chr(ordstrN)

print('orig:', str)
print('or+i:', Posnew)
print('or-i:', Negnew)
```

**Output**: `\SO\64788535.py`

```
orig: a b c e z
or+1: b c d f a
or-1: z a b d y
-
orig: a b c e z
or+i: a d g k h
or-i: a z y y r
```